# How to install ROM or Firmware on LG F160L Korean mobile [soft briked]

Tags: rom, device-firmware, lg

I have LG F160L Korean mobile it was working fine but 5 days ago some app was updated from google play store automatically then suddenly com.google.android.gsf app starting crashed. Not remember gsf or fgsf but it is confirmed it was google android app. Now I don't know it was due to my installed app when it was updated or some thing else. I clicked many times OK but it does not stop. I restarted my phone but it never starts Android OS. When my phone was OK I check in Settings -> About Phone -> model it shows me **F160K** but on phone back after cover removing it is written **F160L**.

**My Phone Current Condition:**

It shows in korean language. May be asking security code

I am so sorry I can't paste external link here that is clickable because I have no reputation yet

Please copy and paste link in browser

www.imageupload.co.uk/image/5NJD

www.imageupload.co.uk/image/5NJE

When I press buttons in combination Volume Up + Home + Power [recovery mode]  it shows error

www.imageupload.co.uk/image/5NJA

When I go to in ClockworkMod Recovery it shows me error and strange thing 
the thing is Lg Optimus Vu2 JB (confusing)

www.imageupload.co.uk/image/5NJR

Error:

www.imageupload.co.uk/image/5NJe

**What I have tried**

I have tried Automatically Flashing the Latest Stock Firmware via the LGMobile Support Tool that downloads firmware and install but when S/W upgrading is in progress it stops after 10% :(

I have tried to install ROM from KDZ flasher it gives error after iPram = 10 KDZ downloaded from lg-phone-firmware dot com for LG F160L  :(

I have tried by downloaded zip file for LG F160L and copying in SD Card and by going inside ClockworkMod after inserting SD Card in phone then install from External SD Card by this method it installs successfully but phone is still in that condition that It was before installing. I tried wipe data, cache and dalvik after installing from SD Card as well :crying:

I actully 4 times wiped data, cache, dalvik

I also did Hard Reset by press this buttom combination Volume Down + Home + Power

There is also one strange thing when I tries to download driver on Windows 7 by connecting phone with PC in Download Mode and in Recovery Mode it installed correct drivers But when I tries to download driver in ClockworkMod it starts installing **LG F200L** Drivers. :eek:

I tried to wipe recovery but could't wipe because I can't see my device in when I run this command *fastboot devices*

**With offline method**

I tried with F160L and F160K KDZ but I am getting this error

```
        20:13:05 : [C:\LGMobileUpgrade] Try to delete folder
    20:13:05 : RemoveDirectory1 Error(2):C:\LGMobileUpgrade
    20:13:05 : Start Date : 2015-02-12 20:13:05
    20:13:05 : ---------- QM Testmode ---------
    20:13:05 : ***** Check Tool Version *****
    20:13:05 : Tool version : 1.5.4.8
    20:13:05 : UpgradeDLL version : 1.2.6.7
    20:13:05 : Current Dir : C:\ProgramData\LGMOBILEAX\B2C_Client
    20:13:05 : LGE USB Driver Version : 
    20:13:05 : Android PDLV Version : 
    20:13:05 : Android NDLV Version : 3.13.0.0
    20:13:05 : ******************************************
    20:13:05 : [C:\ProgramData\LGMOBILEAX\Phone] Try to delete folder
    20:13:05 : SetEmerModeAT()
    20:13:05 : _IsConnectedPhone Call
    20:13:14 : _IsConnectedPhone(2)
    20:13:14 : 0 - NotConnected.
    20:13:14 : 1 - Normal connect success
    20:13:14 : 2 - Emergency connect success
    20:13:14 : *****CheckOS Start********
    20:13:14 : Microsoft_Windows7_Professional_Service Pack 1
    20:13:14 : *****CheckPCSyncPrograms Start*****
    20:13:14 : PCSyncPrograms Not Found - OK and ready to upgrade
    20:13:14 : Checking the connection with the cell phone...
    20:13:14 : dwWaitResetTime(40000 ms)
    20:13:15 : Phone Mode(2)
    20:13:15 : *****GetPhoneType Start*****
    20:13:15 : Phone Type : QCT
    20:13:15 : *****GetPhoneBinaryVersion Start*****
    20:13:16 : Phone Bin Version : 
    20:13:16 : *****Get ESN / IMEI / MEID Start*****
    20:13:16 : Phone type Compare start
    20:13:16 : *****CheckPCSyncPrograms Start*****
    20:13:17 : PCSyncPrograms Not Found - OK and ready to upgrade
    20:13:18 : ****************CheckAndDownload********************
    20:13:18 : ******Extract Start D:\_Downloads\F160K20J_00.kdz*****
    20:13:18 : Model Dll Dir(C:\ProgramData\LGMOBILEAX\Phone\)
    20:13:18 : File Size = 928812201
    20:14:14 : Extract kdz file Success.
    20:14:54 : Extracted C:\ProgramData\LGMOBILEAX\Phone\\F160K20j_Develop.wdb\n
    20:14:54 : WDB(or DZ) FullPath(C:\ProgramData\LGMOBILEAX\Phone\\F160K20j_Develop.wdb)
    20:14:55 : Extracted C:\ProgramData\LGMOBILEAX\Phone\\G1TDR_60.dll\n
    20:14:55 : Model dll FullPath(C:\ProgramData\LGMOBILEAX\Phone\\G1TDR_60.dll)
    20:14:55 : Extracted C:\ProgramData\LGMOBILEAX\Phone\\F160K20j_Develop.wdh\n
    20:14:55 : NNNNN WDB FullPath(C:\ProgramData\LGMOBILEAX\Phone\F160K20j_Develop.wdb)
    20:14:55 : NNNNN Model dll FullPath(C:\ProgramData\LGMOBILEAX\Phone\G1TDR_60.dll)
    20:14:55 : Extract End D:\_Downloads\F160K20J_00.cab
    20:14:55 : ------------------Model.dll Information-------------------
    20:14:55 : Filename : G1TDR_60.dll
    20:14:55 : Version : 1.0.3.4
    20:14:55 : File size : 331776
    20:14:55 : File date : 2012/08/22-15:55:20
    20:14:55 : PC Created date: 2015/02/12-20:14:54
    20:14:55 : ----------------------------------------------------------
    20:14:55 : *****Check LGCM Programs Start*****
    20:14:55 : LGCM Programs Not Found - OK and ready to upgrade
    20:14:55 : *****WorkModelDLL Start*****
    20:15:01 : strPhoneBinaryPath(C:\ProgramData\LGMOBILEAX\Phone\F160K20j_Develop.wdb)
    20:15:01 : strModuleDir(C:\ProgramData\LGMOBILEAX\Phone\)
    20:15:01 : strModelDLLPath(C:\ProgramData\LGMOBILEAX\Phone\G1TDR_60.dll)
    20:15:01 : _DetachDLL Call
    20:15:02 : _DetachDLL Call End
    20:15:02 : Call fn_StartUpgrade
    20:15:02 : ### Start Upgrade - 3GQCT ###
    20:15:02 : ********* 3GQCT Model.dll input Parameter *************
    20:15:02 : MODEL_EVENT     : 32769
    20:15:02 : PhoneBinaryPath : C:\ProgramData\LGMOBILEAX\Phone\F160K20j_Develop.wdb
    20:15:02 : ModuleDir       : C:\ProgramData\LGMOBILEAX\Phone\
    20:15:02 : BootWaitTime    : 15000
    20:15:02 : UsbHighSpeed    : TRUE
    20:15:02 : PhoneMode       : 2
    20:15:02 : NewPhoneBinVersion: F160K20J_00
    20:15:02 : ClearSI          : TRUE
    20:15:02 : AuthMark  : 0
    20:15:02 : ********* 3GQCT Model.dll Parameter END *************
    20:15:02 : fn_StartUpgrade Call success.
    20:15:27 : wParam : 13,     lParam = 4
    20:15:27 : TYPE_WPARAM_MEDIA_ERASE
    20:15:51 : wParam : 13,     lParam = 5
    20:15:51 : TYPE_WPARAM_MEDIA_ERASE
    20:16:10 : wParam : 13,     lParam = 6
    20:16:10 : TYPE_WPARAM_MEDIA_ERASE
    20:16:25 : wParam : 2007,     lParam = 0
    20:16:26 : Step : TYPE_WPARAM_READ_FILES
    20:16:26 : wParam : 13,     lParam = 8
    20:16:26 : TYPE_WPARAM_MEDIA_ERASE
    20:16:26 : wParam : 2008,     lParam = 5
    20:16:26 : Step : TYPE_WPARAM_TOTAL_FILES
    20:16:27 : wParam : 13,     lParam = 10
    20:16:27 : TYPE_WPARAM_MEDIA_ERASE
    20:16:31 : wParam : 20,     lParam = 0
    20:16:31 : wParam : 100,     lParam = 5000
    20:16:31 : _DetachDLL Call
    20:16:31 : _DetachDLL Call End
    20:16:31 : TYPE_WPARAM_UPGRADE_ERROR Error Code = 5000
    20:16:31 : Page_Error ºÎºÐÀÔ´Ï´Ù
    20:16:31 : ¿©±â´Â Retry ºÎºÐÀÔ´Ï´Ù
```

**What should I do?**

Should I try another method with LG F160L KDZ file ?

Should I try with LG F160K KDZ or Zip from SD card?

Should I try with LG F200L KSZ or Zip from SC card?

Should I try to install ClockworkMod again due to mount error if yes then Which method should I try? LG F160 L is not listed in ClockworkMod Website

Answers will be appreciated :)